# How to verify downloaded apk before installing programmatically?

Tags: android, apk

We use something like the following code to install an apk downloaded from our server:

```
public static void install(File file, Activity owner) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    owner.startActivity(intent);
}
```

This works ok, but I'm concerned that an attacker of some kind could replace the apk on the server with one containing malware of some kind. To a user, it might be difficult to tell if such an install was a legitimate upgrade to our app, even if they are presented with a confirmation dialog.

Is it possible to verify programmatically that the signing key contained in the apk matches the one of our app? I'm aware of the existence of [PackageManager.getPackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)), but I couldn't see how to use that to get the signature from an APK that is not yet installed.

Comment: What about using an MD5 checksum?

Comment: We can't use a checksum to verify since I don't know at the time I build this version of the app what the checksum of the *next* version of the app would be

Comment: You can always ask for the MD5 with the apk.

Comment: @samnon I don't really know what that would help with - how can you use an MD5 to verify that the APK does in fact contain a legitimate upgrade to my app, and not some other app?

Comment: If the old version of the app is installed, just go ahead and try to install this new one.  The installation will fail if the signatures don't match, and everything will be the same as when you started.

Comment: @DougStevenson hello this sounds very interesting - do you know that for sure? It sounds like I wouldn't have a problem at all if that is the case.

Comment: You can pretty easily try it yourself by building an apk with the same package name but different signatures.  The installation should fail and specifically say that they don't match.

Comment: @DougStevenson even if that is the case, wouldn't an attacker work around this problem by creating an APK with a similar package name that wouldn't trigger that logic but would still fool an unaware user?

Comment: So, tell me how this attacker gets the APK on the device and initiates the install process.  If you control the download and install flow, what exactly is the nature of this attack?  Even if some rogue app happens to get installed at the user's request, it won't have access to any of the data in the real app.